# Importing custom declaration files with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following TypeScript declaration for an npm package named `foo` which (let just assume for the sake of this example) does not have a declaration file anywhere that I can pull.

```
declare module "foo" {
    export function getPerpetualEnergy(): any[];
    export function endWorldHunger(n: boolean): void;
}
```

I have placed that declaration inside `./typings/foo.d.ts` file and updated my `typeRoots` folders to below (inside `./tsconfig.json` file):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./typings/",
            "./node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.test.ts"
    ]
}
```

and I have tried to use it from a `.ts` like below:

```
import * as foo from 'foo';
foo.endWorldHunger(true);
```

However, it was not able to resolve this. It was complaining to me inside VS Code, too (since I had `noImplicitAny: true`, I suppose, considering [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/17/typescript-2-1-untyped-imports)).

I have changed my consuption to below and it worked out:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/foo.d.ts"/>
import * as foo from 'foo';
foo.endWorldHunger(true);
```

Do I really need that `reference` declaration? I am expecting that I don't since I have specified the `./typings` folder as one of my `typeRoots` but it's possible that I have configured it wrong somehow. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

> I am using TypeScript 2.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Directories used as `typeRoots` are supposed to look like `node_modules` directory, that is, your declaration file for `foo` should be in `typings/foo` folder and be named `index.d.ts` (or you should have `package.json` in `typings/foo` with `types` property pointing to the declaration file).